# File get contents php error

Tags: php, html, api, curl

> Warning: file_get_contents(verdiyev_orxan:ayna12 T.PEMBE_KAPLAN
>   :05326559389 volkan.n1:suem97 Dilanazaka:dilanaz2008): failed to open
>   stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\yni\ayikla.php on line 204
>   0

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) die();
    include "auth/instagram.auth.class.php";
    include "auth/instagram.class.php";
    include "RollingCurl/RollingCurl.php";

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    $extension = ".cookie";


    $dir = "cookies/"; //taranan dosyalar hangi dizine gitsin.
    $data = $_POST['data'];


    $data = file_get_contents($data);
    $users = explode("\n", $data);

    foreach ($users as $user) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $explode = explode(":", $user);
            $username = trim($explode[0]);
            $password = trim($explode[1]);

            $auth = new instaAuth;
            $auth->setCacheFolder($dir);
            $auth->setCacheExtension($extension);

            $login = $auth->_login($username, $password);

            echo $username.' 1'.PHP_EOL;

            sleep(1);

        } 
        catch (Exception $e )
        {
            echo $username.' 0'.PHP_EOL;
            // echo $e->getMessage();
            sleep(1);
        }


    }


    ?>
```

Maybe error on here

```
$data = file_get_contents($data);
        $users = explode("\n", $data);
```

How can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried find out what the value is of `$_POST['data']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change here

```
$data = $_POST['data'];

$data = file_get_contents($data);
$users = explode("\n", $data);
```

to

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$users = explode("\n", $data);
```